# In Powershell I'm receiving an "OutOfMemoryException" when working with files over 1gb

Tags: powershell, file-get-contents

I am doing some file clean up before loading into my data warehouse and have run into a file sizing issue:

```
(Get-Content -path C:\Workspace\workfile\myfile.txt -Raw) -replace '\\"', '"' | Set-Content C:\Workspace\workfile\myfileCLEAN.txt
```

My file is about 2GB. I am receiving the following error and not sure how to correct.

> Get-Content : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was
> thrown, ........

I am NOT a coder, but I do like learning so am building my own data warehouse. So if you do respond, keep my experience level in mind :)

Comment: don't load the whole file ... load it line-by-line and do your replace on each line. then use `Add-Content` to send the result to a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **A performant way of *reading*** a text file line by line - without loading the entire file into memory - is to use a **[`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch)** statement with the **`-File`** parameter.
- **A performant way of *writing*** a text file is to use a **[`System.IO.StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamWriter)** instance.
- As Mathias points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64937363/45375), using verbatim `\"` with the *regex*-based [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) actually replaces `"` *alone*, due to the escaping rules of regexes. While you could address that with `'\\"'`, in this case a simpler and better-performing alternative is to use the `[string]` type's [`Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) method, which operates on *literal* substrings.

To put it all together:

```
# Note: Be sure to use a *full* path, because .NET's working dir. usually
#       differs from PowerShell's.
$streamWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new('C:\Workspace\workfile\myfileCLEAN.txt')

switch -File C:\Workspace\workfile\myfile.txt {
  default { $streamWriter.WriteLine($_.Replace('\"', '"')) }
}

$streamWriter.Close()
```

Note: If you're using an *old* version of Windows PowerShell, namely version 4 or below, use
`New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter 'C:\Workspace\workfile\myfileCLEAN.txt'`
instead of
`[System.IO.StreamWriter]::new('C:\Workspace\workfile\myfileCLEAN.txt')`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I upgraded to v5 and wow! this works great and is super fast :) Thank you so much!

Comment: **mklement0** - I'm working on some comparisons and will write a proper question soon, but is `switch` w/ `-File` the most performant way of reading? Interesting we aren't doing a `StreamReader` to complement the writer. I need to use `ConvertFrom-Csv` in my case, so I'm still working on figuring out what will be the best to measure, but thought I'd ask while I'm working on it

Comment: @immobile2, among native PowerShell features, `switch -File` is the fastest method. I'm not certain, but I think its performance is comparable to a `StreamReader` loop or a `[IO.File]::ReadLines()` loop. The use of .NET methods is less obvious to PowerShell users, and there's the pitfall of the working-directory mismatch. Also, `switch` offers sophisticated filtering functionality (not needed here).

Comment: Thanks! It is actually slower than my piping at the moment, but I think that is the `StreamWriter` for some reason. I'm going to go with an `[IO.File]` method though because my `switch` statement right now is needlessly doing a wildcard compare to identify the header and then stripping the header off later before writing to file

Answer (score 2):

`Get-Content -Raw` makes PowerShell read *the entire file* into a single string.

.NET can't store individual objects over 2GB in size in memory, and each character in a string takes up 2 bytes, so after reading the first ~1 billion characters (roughly equivalent to a 1GB ASCII-encoded text file), it reaches the memory limit.

Remove the `-Raw` switch, `-replace` is perfectly capable of operating on multiple input strings at once:

```
(Get-Content -path C:\Workspace\workfile\myfile.txt) -replace '\"', '"' | Set-Content C:\Workspace\workfile\myfileCLEAN.txt
```

Beware that `-replace` is a *regex* operator, and if you want to remove `\` from a string, you need to escape it:

```
(Get-Content -path C:\Workspace\workfile\myfile.txt) -replace '\\"', '"' | Set-Content C:\Workspace\workfile\myfileCLEAN.txt
```

While this will work, it'll still be slow due to the fact that we're still loading >2GB of data into memory *before* applying `-replace` and writing to the output file.

Instead, you might want to *pipe* the output from `Get-Content` to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-Content -path C:\Workspace\workfile\myfile.txt |ForEach-Object {
  $_ -replace '\\"','"'
} |Set-Content C:\Workspace\workfile\myfileCLEAN.txt
```

This allows `Get-Content` to start pushing output prior to finishing reading the file, and PowerShell therefore no longer needs to allocate as much memory as before, resulting in faster execution.

Comment: This does work but is slow with a 2GB file taking almost an hour to process. Any hints on helping to speed up the process?

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content` loads the whole file into memory.

Try processing line by line to improve memory utilization.

```
$infile = "C:\Workspace\workfile\myfile.txt"
$outfile = "C:\Workspace\workfile\myfileCLEAN.txt"

foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($infile)) {
    Add-Content -Path $outfile -Value ($line -replace '\\"','"')
}
```

Comment: `Get-Content` only loads the whole file into memory if you use the `-Raw` switch or enclose the call in `(...)`. While `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()` is an efficient way to read a file, you're negating the performance benefits by using `Add-Content` in a loop, which opens and closes the output file in each iteration.

Comment: This works but is as slow as using Get-Content. Only advantage I saw was less taxing on memory and I could more easily monitor the progress.