# How to concatenate characters after recognition and interception in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

I want to turn the following input:

```
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.cdscheduler" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.callhistory.asl.conf" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/asl" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
    Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.mkb" sharing output destination "/private/var/log/keybagd.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.mkb.internal".
    Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.mkb.internal" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.mkb".
```

into the following output:

```
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:ASL Module "com.apple.cdscheduler" claims selected messages.Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:ASL Module "com.apple.callhistory.asl.conf" claims selected messages.Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/asl" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
May 13 00:30:00 BBAOMACBOOKAIR2 syslogd[113]: Configuration Notice:ASL Module "com.apple.mkb" sharing output destination "/private/var/log/keybagd.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.mkb.internal".Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.mkb.internal" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.mkb".
```

That is, the indented lines should be joined to the preceding non-indented line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `May ...` lines have no leading whitespace:

- If the file is small enough to fit into memory as a whole, combine [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) `-Raw` with the regex-based [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) (redirect the output to a file as needed; if the input text is already in memory, simply use *it* as the LHS):

```bash
(Get-Content -Raw file.log).TrimEnd() -replace '\r?\n\s+', ' '
```

- Otherwise, use a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) with the `-File` and `-Regex` parameters:

```bash
& {
  $mergedLine = ''
  switch -Regex -File file.log {
    '^\S' {  # 'May ...' line, no leading whitespace.
      if ($mergedLine) { $mergedLine } # output previous 
      $mergedLine = $_
    }
    default { # Subsequent, indented line (leading whitespace)
      $mergedLine += ' ' + $_.TrimStart()
    }
  }
  $mergedLine # output final merged line
}
```

Note:

- For readability, the solutions above place a space char. between the merged (joined) lines; remove the use of `' '` from the code above to join them without a separator (as in the sample output in your question).
- You can pipe the `& { ... }` solution to [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) for output, though if performance is paramount, you may want to use the [`System.IO.StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamWriter) .NET type for faster writing, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64938276/45375).

An equivalent `awk`-based solution can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108500/45375) to your follow-up question about a native macOS solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would first make sure it's a multi-line string (rather than an array of strings), then use RegEx to split based on the date/time stamp, and for each multi-line bit passed trim any whitespace from a line, and join the lines together into one line. That can be done with something like this

```
$LogText -join "`n" -split '[\r\n]+\s*(?=\w+ \d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)'|
    ForEach-Object {$_.trimstart() -replace '[\r\n]+\s*'}
```